# What should be the directory structure for the param having prefix in Nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a route like `/en/rent-:productSlug`

What should be the directory structure of the above route as the parameter `productSlug` is having prefix `rent`?

Comment: Nuxt2 or 3? Btw, why not `/en/rent/productSlug`?

Comment: @kissu Nuxt 2. We have a requirement of rent-:productSlug.

Comment: @kissu looks like I should use this https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-router/#extendroutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in the docs, you have several ways of extending the router: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/file-system-routing#extending-the-router

https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-extras-module is usually enough, not sure if this may help for the prefix. If it doesn't, you can of course write it in the configuration as you found out.